# Get multiple value in one row transpose based on criteria on another row

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet that populated from Google Form. It comes with a column for the company name, and an employee name. The company column can have the same or duplicate value, but the employee column doesn't. So, how I can get a company name with all the employee name in one row?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) and [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en&ref_topic=3105422) functions if you are using Google Spreadsheet. Here is an example:

[image]

---

***Formula*** in `D2`:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

---

***Formula*** in `E2`:

- *Option 1*

  ```
  =TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=D2))
  ```
- *Option 2, the above can get sluggish really quick, so maybe instead use:*

  ```
  =TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))=D2))
  ```
- *Option 3, Even using [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) is a possibility:*

  ```
  =TRANSPOSE(QUERY({$A$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA(B:B))},"Select Col2 where Col1='"&D2&"'"))
  ```
- *Option 4, [Found](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/9554508?hl=en) a way to just use a single formula in `E2`:*

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRIM(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(D2:INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D)))=A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))&"|",),,9^99))),"|")),COUNTA(D2:INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D))),100))
  ```

This way when you add data to column `A:B` the formula will auto-update your desired output:

[image]

Comment: it works flawlessly, I just have learning google app script to accomplish that. And still not find a way. thank you

Comment: @randuwe Glad it works for you! I've edited the answer with something I found on the internet. That way you would only have to enter the formula once. Since I'm not experienced with GS there might even be a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

#### one-cell solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SORT(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1))), 
 SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)), QUERY(QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0), 
 "limit 0", 1)&"♦", )),,999^99))), "♦")})
```

[image: 0]