# Transpose rows of sheet 1 to sheet2 based on a column value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, transpose

I have two sheets below. I have also added sample data and desired output in the sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WBzSdtevsWH1WiZecRTwM-OPM3eYYrA0Ocoje3ZE8Y/edit#gid=1495165102).

Posts Sheet:

```
 id |   title   |  image   
 1  |  title 1  |  1.jpg   
 2  |  title 2  |  2.jpg   
 3  |  title 3  |  3.jpg
```

Metadata Sheet:

```
  meta_id |  meta_key      |  value   |  post_id
     1    |  meta_title    |  1       |     1
     2    |  meta_keyword  |  1       |     1
     3    |  meta_likes    |  1       |     1
     4    |  meta_title    |  2       |     2
     5    |  meta_keyword  |  2       |     2
     7    |  meta_title    |  3       |     3
     8    |  meta_keyword  |  3       |     3
     9    |  meta_likes    |  3       |     3
```

As you can see, there is no guarantee every post will have all the metadata.

Explanation on each sheet:

**Posts Sheet -**

> Posts sheet consist of a list of posts, its title and image. `id`
> column in it is unique and will never repeat. So basically one post
> will have one row.

**Metadata Sheet -**

> Metadata sheet consists of various information related to an individual
> post. It contains key-value data with a mapping to the main post sheet
> via the post_id column.

**How both need to be joined-**

> Each metadata in the metadata sheet should be added to relevant rows
> in the posts sheet based on the post_id column in metadata. So after
> merging a row in the posts sheet will have columns named `meta_title`,
> `meta_keyword` & `meta_likes`.

**And example of the column headers after merge will look as below:**

```
meta_id | meta_key  |  value  |  meta_title | meta_keyword | meta_likes
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447723/get-multiple-value-in-one-row-transpose-based-on-criteria-on-another-row), however, it only works if meta_table has just one key. In my case, the metatable can consist of multiple keys and values.

Sample data & desired output added in [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WBzSdtevsWH1WiZecRTwM-OPM3eYYrA0Ocoje3ZE8Y/edit#gid=1495165102).

Comment: Please format the input and output or provide them in images

Comment: I think what you provided is not enough for others to understand your desired output. What is the first table for? What is the matching rule and output of the last header?

Comment: Here is a blank sheet created specifically for this question.  Feel free to paste some sample data there to make it easier to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WBzSdtevsWH1WiZecRTwM-OPM3eYYrA0Ocoje3ZE8Y/edit

Comment: @MattKing Sorry for the trouble. I have updated the question with more details and added sample data in the sheet you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on [this shared sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WBzSdtevsWH1WiZecRTwM-OPM3eYYrA0Ocoje3ZE8Y/edit#gid=710390970) from the comments in the original post,  I made a new tab called MK.Help where I left two options.  The first consists of two formulas, the second, just one.

This formula in cell A1, just brings over the posts:

```
=QUERY(Posts!A:C,"where B<>''")
```

This formula populates the meta data for each post.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&D1:F1,{Metadata!D:D&Metadata!B:B,Metadata!C:C},2,0)))
```

There is also another potentially simpler option which just QUERY()s the meta data in a fixed way. That is, you cannot control the order of the columns, they happen alphabetically.

```
=QUERY(Metadata!A:D,"select D,MAX(C) where D is not null group by D pivot B")
```