# Transpose rows to column grouped by a column in Googles Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, transpose

Change data in Google sheet for better understanding based on a column value

**From this:**

```
entity_id  |  data_key      |  data_value   
    1      |  name          |  some name
    1      |  author        |  john
    1      |  likes         |  12 
    2      |  name          |  another name
    2      |  author        |  sam 
    3      |  name          |  different name 
    3      |  author        |  mary
    3      |  likes         |  3
```

**To this:**

```
entity_id  |  name          |   author    |    likes 
    1      |  some name     |    john     |     12     
    2      |  another name  |    sam      |      
    3      |  different name|    mary     |     3
```

I checked features like transpose, it falls short of what I actually need.

Comment: This appears to show the same underlying problem as the one you asked about a few hours earlier: [Transpose rows of sheet 1 to sheet2 based on a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871163/transpose-rows-of-sheet-1-to-sheet2-based-on-a-column-value). You should edit the original question to clarify it, instead of asking a new question, if that is the case.

Comment: @andrewjames Yes, the issues do have some similarities. However, these are two problems I was struggling with the last 2 days. This question is related to rearranging values in a single sheet. The previous one was merging to sheets data. I felt adding two different queries in one post will result in unwanted complexity, especially as the original data & the output are different.

Comment: OK - understood, but I still think the underlying transposition logic problem is basically the same. Just a suggestion for the future: To avoid any misunderstandings it might be helpful to clarify the differences between such questions, in the questions themselves.

Comment: Will do that in future. Really appreciate you taking the time for clarifying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the function in the below snippet as a custom function:

```js
const data = [
  ['entity_id', 'data_key', 'data_value'],
  [1, 'name', 'some name'],
  [1, 'author', 'john'],
  [1, 'likes', 12],
  [2, 'name', 'another name'],
  [2, 'author', 'sam'],
  [3, 'name', 'different name'],
  [3, 'author', 'mary'],
  [3, 'likes', 3],
];

/**
 *@customfunction
 */
const myTranspose = range => {
  range.shift();
  const headers = [];
  const undefToStr = value => (undefined === value ? '' : value);
  const obj = range.reduce((acc, row) => {
    if (!acc[row[0]]) acc[row[0]] = {};
    acc[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2];
    if (-1 === headers.indexOf(row[1])) headers.push(row[1]);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (acc, entry) => {
      const row = [entry[0]];
      headers.forEach(header => row.push(undefToStr(entry[1][header])));
      acc.push(row);
      return acc;
    },
    [['entity_id', ...headers]]
  );
};

console.log(myTranspose(data));
```

The result of the function in Google Sheets:
[image: myTranspose function]

The function first builds and then transposes it into a new 2D array.

Comment: You've got some hard-coded data in there, 'entity_id'... That's not very flexible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=newTab(A1,A2:C9)
```

with custom function

```
function newTab(title,data){
  var headers=[]
  var items = new Map()
  var n = 0
  data.forEach(function(elem){
    items.set(elem[1],'')
    n= Math.max(n,elem[0])
  })
  items.forEach(function(value, key) {headers.push(key)})
  var result = Array.from({ length: n + 1 }, () => Array.from({ length: headers.length + 1 }, () => ''));
  result[0] = [title, ...headers]
  data.forEach(function(elem){
    result[elem[0]][headers.indexOf(elem[1])+1]=elem[2]
    result[elem[0]][0]=elem[0]
  })
  return(result)
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12LOBTcialZ8wef9enII-hFsjrRnuOhx35_EXtg4Zreo/copy

Comment: You've got a lot of hard-coded data in there, the range, the headers... That's not very flexible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is located columns A to C

```
={A1,transpose(unique(B2:B));arrayformula(ROW(A2:A)-1),arrayformula(iferror(vlookup((row(A2:A)-1)&"|"&transpose(unique(B2:B)),{arrayformula(A2:A&"|"&B2:B),arrayformula(C2:C)},2,0)))}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12LOBTcialZ8wef9enII-hFsjrRnuOhx35_EXtg4Zreo/copy